# usage of "außerdem" with "dazu"

Tags: word-choice

```
außerdem hätten wir gerne noch ein Croissant dazu bitte.
```

translates to

```
We'd also like a croissant please.
```

is `dazu` needed? as `außerdem` + `noch` already portrays `also` and `yet another`. Also curious how the meaning changes if `dazu` is removed.

Comment: Who translates it like this?

Comment: "dazu" is "with it" here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "dazu" is needed - to express that you already ordered something to eat/drink and order someting more while consuming it in the same manner. This single word makes the difference if this crossaint is your only order (*dazu* removed) or an add on (*dazu* used).

Thus a better translation would be:

*We'd also like to have a croissant with it, please.*

PS: "already ordered" is not to be confused with any previous order. It means you are somewhere from "ordered one literal second ago" up to "you finished consuming your last order one literal second ago".